# Passing Dynamic Variables From Facebook Ad Link UTMs?

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api

Does Facebook have any known variables that can be set and passed on in a UTM parameter from ad link clicks?

Something like {userid} in the example below:
http://www.example.com/?utm_campaign=facebook-summer-promotion&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=facebook.com&utm_content={userid}

Comment: What do you need user id for? And I'm pretty sure for privacy reason you can't get it

Comment: @WizKid User ID is just an example, but I understand that'd be a privacy issue (on the FB side and the GA side). Just looking to see if we can pass on any information dynamically (geo, campaign name, ad location, etc).